# what is the generic name for mustache-style databinding?

Tags: javascript, angular, handlebars.js, mustache

I've implemented mustache.js which uses a databinding style like this:

```
{{user.FirstName}}
{{user.LastName}}
etc
```

Angular2 uses a similar approach for its databinding. What is the generic name for this implementation? For example, could I say that "both mustache.js and ng2 use mustache-style templates for databinding"? Or is there a better way to make this statement?

Comment: Mustache doesn't provide any data binding, it simply renders a string that can them be injected with `node.innerHTML = templateString`.

Answer (score 2):

[**Interpolation**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/glossary.html)

*A form of property data binding in which a template expression between double-curly braces renders as text. That text may be concatenated with neighboring text before it is assigned to an element property or displayed between element tags, as in this example.

*My current hero is {{hero.name}}
Read more about interpolation in the Template Syntax page.*